# Using Google Analytics Measurement Protocol could link collected data with Adwords?

Tags: php, protocols, analytics, measurement

I created this piece of code to use Google Analytics Measurement Protocol instead of the google provided javascript, analytics.js in one of my page.

Recently I was playing with analytics javascript code, and I found that many times it will not collect data if something is blocking tracking codes (eg.: analytics.js) like when PrivDog is installed (amongs others).

The original idea is coming from here, but this is for wordpress.
http://www.stumiller.me/implementing-google-analytics-measurement-protocol-in-php-and-wordpress/
I modified the code to send data with sockets. (and without the wordpress functions library)

```
$gclid = $_GET['gclid'];
if (!empty($gclid)) {
    setcookie("gclid", $gclid, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
}

// Handle the parsing of the _ga cookie or setting it to a unique identifier
function gaParseCookie()
{
    if (isset($_COOKIE['_ga'])) {
        list($version, $domainDepth, $cid1, $cid2) = split('[\.]', $_COOKIE["_ga"], 4);
        $contents = array('version' => $version, 'domainDepth' => $domainDepth, 'cid' => $cid1 . '.' . $cid2);
        $cid = $contents['cid'];
    } else {
        $cid = gaGenUUID();
    }
    return $cid;
}

// Generate UUID v4 function - needed to generate a CID when one isn't available
function gaGenUUID()
{
    return sprintf('%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x',
            // 32 bits for "time_low"
            mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff),
            // 16 bits for "time_mid"
            mt_rand(0, 0xffff),
            // 16 bits for "time_hi_and_version",
            // four most significant bits holds version number 4
            mt_rand(0, 0x0fff) | 0x4000,
            // 16 bits, 8 bits for "clk_seq_hi_res",
            // 8 bits for "clk_seq_low",
            // two most significant bits holds zero and one for variant DCE1.1
            mt_rand(0, 0x3fff) | 0x8000,
            // 48 bits for "node"
            mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff)
    );
}

function gaBuildHit($method = null, $info = null)
{
    global $gclid;

    if ($method && $info) {
        // Standard params
        $v = 1;
        $tid = "UA-XXXXXXX-XX"; // Put your own Analytics ID in here
        $cid = gaParseCookie();

        if (empty($gclid)) {
            $gclid = $_COOKIE['gclid'];
        }

// Register a PAGEVIEW
        if ($method === 'pageview') {
            // Send PageView hit
            $data = array(
                'v' => $v,
                'tid' => $tid,
                'cid' => $cid,
                'gclid' => $gclid,
                't' => 'pageview',
                'dt' => $info['title'],
                'dp' => $info['slug']
            );
            gaFireHit($data);
        } // end pageview method
        //
        // Register an ECOMMERCE TRANSACTION (and an associated ITEM)
        else if ($method === 'ecommerce') {
            // Send Transaction hit
            $data = array(
                'v' => $v,
                'tid' => $tid,
                'cid' => $cid,
                'gclid' => $gclid,
                't' => 'transaction',
                'ti' => $info['tid'], // Transaction ID
                'ta' => 'SI',
                'tr' => $info['price'], // transaction value (native currency)
                'ts' => $info['shipping'], // transaction shipping (native currency)
                'cu' => $info['cc'] // currency code
            );
            gaFireHit($data);
            // Set up Item params
            if ($info['info']->product_name) {
                $in = urlencode($info['info']->product_name); // item name;
                $ip = $tr;
                $iq = 1;
                $ic = urlencode($info['info']->product_id); // item SKU
                $iv = urlencode('SI'); // Product Category - we use 'SI' in all cases, you may not want to
                // Send Item hit
                $data = array(
                    'v' => $v,
                    'tid' => $tid,
                    'cid' => $cid,
                    'gclid' => $gclid,
                    't' => 'item',
                    'ti' => $ti,
                    'in' => $in,
                    'ip' => $ip,
                    'iq' => $iq,
                    'ic' => $ic,
                    'iv' => $iv,
                    'cu' => $cu
                );
                gaFireHit($data);
            }
        } else if ($method === 'event') {
            $data = array(
                'v' => $v,
                'tid' => $tid,
                'cid' => $cid,
                'gclid' => $gclid,
                'ec' => $info['category'],
                'ea' => $info['event'],
                'el' => $info['label'],
                'ev' => $info['value']
            );
            gaFireHit($data);
        }
    }
}

// See ttps://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide
function gaFireHit($data = null)
{
    if ($data) {
        $url = 'https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect';
        $getString .= '?payload_data&';
        $getString .= http_build_query($data);
        $result = socketPost($url, $getString, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        return $result;
    }
    return false;
}

function socketPost($url, $post_string, $ua = null)
{
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    // workout port and open socket
    $port = isset($parts['port']) ? $parts['port'] : 80;
    $success = $fp = fsockopen($parts['host'], $port, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if ($fp) {
        // create output string
        $output = "POST " . $parts['path'] . " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        if (is_string($ua)) {
            $output .= "User-Agent: " . $ua . "\r\n";
        }
        $output .= "Host: " . $parts['host'] . "\r\n";
        $output .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
        $output .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($post_string) . "\r\n";
        $output .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
        $output .= isset($post_string) ? $post_string : '';
        // send output to $url handle
        $success = fwrite($fp, $output);
        fclose($fp);
    }
    return $success ? true : false;
}
//examples:
//page hit

$data = array(
    'title' => 'Page title',
    'slug' => $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
);

gaBuildHit('pageview', $data);

//ecommerce

$data = array(
    'tid' => $order_id_in_merchant_system,
    'cc' => 'AUD', // the currency code
    'price' => $order_total, // the price
    'shipping' => $order_shipping, // the shipping cost
    'country' => 'AU' // the country ISO code
);

gaBuildHit('ecommerce', $data);
```

The code itself is working just fine. I put here for you to get the idea.

Question is, I dont really see the flow, how could an Adwords Click get tracked here. Like, if there is no _ga cookie set before (then gaParseCookie creates one), how could analytics connect the tracked event into eg.: an Analytics keyword the click coming from? Is that possible with Measurement Protocol?

Comment: i mean how could adwords tracking variable gclid get tracked with Measurement Protocol

Comment: by adding 'gclid' => $gclid to the request to Measurement Protocol Adwords can be tracked, i have modified the code accordingly. so this question is solved, can be closed